# VTC on beta sites?

Tags: discussion

It would appear (though maybe I just can't see it) that there are exactly 4 people either voting to close, or reviewing close votes. Unless betas are different?, we're kind of stuck here no? Thoughts?

No rush to close things of course, just interested in your thoughts...

Comment: Most of the questions I have closed lately have had exactly 3 close votes by the time I have reviewed them.  It is definitely better than several months ago when it was usually only 1 vote to close.  I think as we get more active users the moderators will have a bit less work in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

When Security.SE was in beta and still very small, the mod group would look at close votes, and as @FriendOfGeorge has said, we'd help them on their way if we came to a consensus.

(Sometimes we would re-open, depending on discussion/argument)

Flagging helps the mods see dodgy posts, and dropping a note in chat helps others see a post they may have missed.

The only real solution is to encourage users to vote, and in any case this problem vanishes once the site gets big enough.

Comment: That makes sense of course :)  Somehow, when writing this post, it slipped my mind that mods can, of course, complete the close process, short of the 5 votes required for the community to do it. /facepalm  ;)